# MediaElement isn't rendered at ContentRendered

Tags: wpf, splash-screen, mediaelement

I'm making a splash-screen for my WPF application and it's just a window with a `MediaElement` at the background and some text over it.

The splash-screen's window is loading the main window at [`ContentRendered`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.contentrendered.aspx) (in another thread, should it matter), displays it, then hides itself.

The problem is that the `MediaElement` doesn't begin to play until the splash-screen's window is out of the `ContentRendered` event. So the result is an empty splash-screen window that begins to play it's animation only when it's hidden.

*P.S. It's pretty hard to describe the problem without visual aids, so if I could expand any further, please let me know could I do that.*

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think the rendering of the MediaElement has nothing to do with its source beeing played.

What you should do:
Register for the [MediaOpened](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.mediaopened%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)-event of the MediaElement. Here you now, that the video itself has been loaded and is prepared for playing.

Now you can start loading your main window.